# how to fix sql case syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

work on sql-server-2005

```
  SELECT    A.specific_customization_id ,
            A.customization_id ,
            A.customization_value ,
            A.customization_price ,
            A.customization_cost ,
            A.customization_code ,
            A.customization_check ,
            A.sort_order ,
            A.option_code ,
            A.product_id ,
            A.image_1 ,
            A.image_2 ,
            A.MainProductID ,
            A.customization_product_id ,
            A.inactive ,
            A.customization_description ,
            A.customization_select ,
            A.UOM ,
            A.allow_recur ,
            auto_reorder = CASE A.MainProductID --it's an int type column
                             WHEN NULL THEN A.allow_recur
                             ELSE ( SELECT  allow_recur
                                    FROM    wc_product
                                    WHERE   product_id = A.MainProductID
                                  )
                           END
  FROM      dbo.wc_product_specific A
  WHERE     A.product_id = 1133
```

Using the above query I want to set auto_reorder column value .want to set two login

1. When My MainProductID column is null I want to set allow_recur column value
2. When it’s not null I want to set another table column value

My logic 2) works fine ,fail to understand why does 1) not work? Help me to fix the problem?

If have any query plz ask thanks in advance.

Comment: *but why does 1) not work?* - **how does it not work?** You need to ask a better quality question if you want people to spend time helping you fix YOUR problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:?

```
SELECT    A.specific_customization_id ,
            A.customization_id ,
            A.customization_value ,
            A.customization_price ,
            A.customization_cost ,
            A.customization_code ,
            A.customization_check ,
            A.sort_order ,
            A.option_code ,
            A.product_id ,
            A.image_1 ,
            A.image_2 ,
            A.MainProductID ,
            A.customization_product_id ,
            A.inactive ,
            A.customization_description ,
            A.customization_select ,
            A.UOM ,
            A.allow_recur ,
            A.auto_reorder = CASE  --it's an int type column
                             WHEN A.MainProductID IS NULL THEN A.allow_recur
                             ELSE B.allow_recur
                             END

  FROM      dbo.wc_product_specific A
            left outer join wc_product B on  B.product_id = A.MainProductID
  WHERE     A.product_id = 1133
```

Comment: auto_reorder = CASE   --it's an int type column
                            WHEN A.MainProductID IS NULL THEN A.allow_recur
                            ELSE ( SELECT   allow_recur
                                   FROM     wc_product
                                   WHERE    product_id = A.MainProductID
                                 )
                       END